# React.js - Use cdn methods

Tags: reactjs

I have loaded bingmaps js file into component using new script tag, and in callback I could see script loaded.

But while I try to user `new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#react-bingmaps')` exception thrown in console as `Microsoft' is not defined`

Please let me know which is the right way to use external js file methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you included CDN,`Microsoft` is attached to global `window` object.

You need to access it using `window` object.

On top of code before using it, add below line.

```
let Microsoft = window.Microsoft;
//rest code
```